# Configuring Terminator key bindings by editing configuration file

Tags: terminal

I had been working on `gnome-terminal` for 4 months now, and configured my key bindings according to my needs using the schema options provided by `gsettings`.

My interest has shifted towards `Terminator` now.

How do I configure key bindings of `Terminator` according to my needs without using GUI. Because I want to be able to script this process if I ever need to work on other machines.

Which file holds the key bind configuration of `Terminator` so that I can edit it with script?

I already checked for the configuration file `~/.config/terminator/config` which is mentioned in `man` page of `Terminator`, this file does not exist in my system.

Answer (score 2):

Terminator's config file is `~/.config/terminator/config`.

It is only created when you change something in its preferences.

Comment: I already checked for this file before posting my question although I forgot to mention in my question, `~/.config/terminator/config` does not exist in my system

Comment: It is created as soon as you change something in the prefs dialog.